# Website displaying without CSS when links mistyped

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm in the process of making a website for myself but there is a niggling problem that if you type a URL and end with / or /(any characters) then you get a page without CSS.

For example:

```
http://www.acnorris.uk/contact                     works fine
/contact/                                         displays without CSS/JS/images
/contact/anythinghere                            displays without CSS/JS/images
```

The same also goes for my 404 page

```
http://www.acnorris.uk/pretendlink                   shows 404 fine
/pretendlink/                                        no CSS/JS/images
/pretendlink/somethingelse                           no CSS/JS/images
```

I have spent time looking at editing htaccess files (it's hosted on a plesk server) but
I can't work this out. Hopefully someone can offer a solution so even mistyped links
display with CSS.

Comment: I think we need to get your htaccess file, too. I would bet that is where your issue is. Also, are you using a MVC Framework (Cake, Yii, etc) that does routing? If so, we'll need to see your routes, too.

Comment: If you are working with PHP you may want to consider calling these files with absolute paths based on variables, much like Wordpress does with its site_url function. For example: <?php echo site_url().'css/mystyle.css'; ?>

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the CSS because the browser is searching in different folders. For example, if a browser requests the `/contact` page, and finds `<link href=contact.css>`, it will then request `/contact.css`. If instead, the request is for `/contact/`, it will request `/contact/contact.css`.

This behaviour may also be affected by the `<base>` HTML element.

---

I don't know what you're using at the server end to translate URLs to filenames, but I'll throw in one detailed example below.

### General Structure

One common solution is to put all the files related to, for instance, your contact page in the same folder:

- `/contact/index.php`
- `/contact/contact.css`
- `/contact/contact.js`.

From the index page, you can refer to the files using relative URLs (`src=contact.js`, `href=contact.css`). Any site-wide files should be placed in the web root or a subfolder of the web root, and referred to using an absolute URL (`/site.js` or `/js/site.js`). You should probably choose better file names.

### Index file

In order for Apache to load the index file, you need to use [**mod_dir**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html) to specify a set of file names to search for. The server will attempt to load the files in the order specified:

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

### Trailing slash

The `DirectoryIndex` will only take effect if the URL ends in a slash (`/`), so [**mod_dir**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html) automatically redirects a URL that specifies a folder without a trailing slash.

Note that the auto-redirect can be turned off in later versions of Apache:

```
    DirectorySlash Off
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should use quotes around attributes to help prevent XSS.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: In my example above, quotes are unnecessary. If you're referring to attibute quotes in a wider context, such as programatically producing HTML based on user input, then just adding quotes is inadequate.

Comment: Quotes **help** prevent XSS by stringifying attributes so any injected code becomes useless. Code can still be injected even after the page has loaded and displayed, so it is generally a good idea to use quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice everyone,

I figured out the problem was to do with me setting relative instead of absolute links which sorted out the problem. Rookie mistake :(

Adam